# How can I combine rows in a pandas dataframe that have similar values in one column to produce the mean of their values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, google-colaboratory

Apologies for the wording of the question but I can illustrate my problem more clearly below.

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

| Region | Value |
| --- | --- |
| London North | 8 |
| North Yorkshire | 4 |
| London South | 6 |
| South Yorkshire | 6 |

How can I combine the London rows and the Yorkshire rows and produce the mean of their values?

(This is a simplified example of the dataframe I am working with which consists of approx. 3000 rows.)

I would like to get the following dataframe:

| Wider Region | Avg. Value |
| --- | --- |
| London | 7 |
| Yorkshire | 5 |

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If I have answered your question, then please accept my answer by clicking the checkmark next to the solution. Please see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Thank you for the welcome and thank you for your swift reply. To be honest I used the answer provided by @adhg simply because it is the one I saw first and it worked a charm. Nevertheless, thanks again for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to define what makes **London** and **Yorkshire** (or other cities) as they have a leading prefix or postfix such as 'North', 'South' etc.

An example would be:

```
my_territories = ['London','Yorkshire']
df['territories'] = df.apply(lambda x: [t for t in my_territories if t in x['Region']][0], axis=1)
```

which will result in:

```
    Region          Value   territories
0   London North    8       London
1   North Yorkshire 4       Yorkshire
2   London South    6       London
3   South Yorkshire 6       Yorkshire
```

and

```
df.groupby(['territories'])['Value'].mean().reset_index()
```

will return the desired result:

```
    territories Value
0   London      7
1   Yorkshire   5
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many approaches that can be taken to this depending on the values of all the data, the process and many other reasons. This is a straightforward approach if you can identify all of the `exclude_words`

```
exclude_words = ['North', 'South']
df['Wider Region'] = df['Region'].replace(exclude_words, '', regex=True).str.strip()
df.groupby('Wider Region', as_index=False).mean()
Out[1]: 
  Wider Region  Value
0       London      7
1    Yorkshire      5
```

You can use this line of code to help you find `exclude_words`:

```
df['Region'].str.split().explode().unique()

Out[1]:
array(['London', 'North', 'Yorkshire', 'South'], dtype=object)
```

From there, you would just identify the words that you can exclude, so that you can group.